How to get the current exception object in C++ Builder (replacement for ExceptObject)?
I am looking for a function/code that returns the current exception object. In other words, the exception object that represents the exception currently being handled (by the catch block).
For example:
  try
  {
    // throws an exception
  }
  catch (const std::exception& Exc)
  {
    DoSomething();
  }

void DoSomething() {
  // How to get the "Exc" here?
}

In other words, I need a C++ equivalent of Delphi's ExceptObject function.
The code above is just an example. The real code looks more like this:
  catch (...)
  {
    A3rdPartyCode();
  }

void A3rdPartyCode() {
  MyCode();
}

void MyCode() {
  // Does not work, returns NULL:
  TObject* = ExceptObject(); 

  // ???
  // Need to know the current exception, if present
}


Just pass it in, void DoSomething(std::exception const& exc) { /*...*/ }

But if "for reasons" you can't do that, you can use std::rethrow_exception.

@Eljay It is a simplified code which serves only as an example. The real code calls my function through 3rd party code, so it is not possible to alter function's header.

Are you looking for std::current_exception?

@zdf Something like that, but not typed. In other words, it should work for "catch(...)".

Perhaps you are looking for Lippincott function?

@АлександрКулагин std::current_exception() works inside of catch (...). It simply returns a capture of the current exception, whatever it happens to be. However, you can't access the captured exception from std::current_exception() itself, all you can do is pass it to std::rethrow_exception(). If you need access to the captured exception, you will have to catch it again after rethrowing it.

Most likely you are looking for a solution in the wrong way, trying to match Delphi and C++ line for line. Anyway, here's an example of how std::current_exception can be used:
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void f()
{
  throw "exception from f()";
}

std::exception_ptr pce;

void g() noexcept
{
  try
  {
    f();
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    pce = std::current_exception();
  }
}

void h() noexcept
{
  try
  {
    if ( pce )
      std::rethrow_exception(pce);
  }
  catch (const char* e)
  {
    std::cout << e;
  }
}

int main()
{
  g();
  h();
}

std::current_exception is useful, for example, if you are processing a collection in a secondary thread using a function that can throw for each item in the collection. Instead of interrupting the processing, you can store the exception and forward it to the main thread later.

Just note that this approach is the equivalent of using Delphi's AcquireExceptionObject() rather than ExceptObj().  Delphi allows you to peek at the current exception without taking ownership of it.  C++ does not.
